# Como Instalar SDK de PayPal en Laravel

Tags: paypal, sdk

Hola estoy tratando de usar el sdk de paypal, tengo un tutorial donde uso anouar/paypalpayment, instalo el sdk a través de composer.json, luego en config/app.php añado un provider y un alias, luego finalmente en prompt escribo el comando: php artisan vendor:publish y finalmente crea **config/paypal_payment.php**

La cuestión es que por otra necesidad estoy tratando de instalar el SDK pero no usando Anouar y la pagina de PayPal me indica hacerlo desde el prompt usando el comando: composer require "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php:*" lo cual ya hice, pero solo hasta ahi he llegado no más. Alguna alma piadosa me podrá indicar los pasos que necesito seguir y si es que también debo  añadir algun provider o aliases y que comando debo ejecutar para que cree el file **config/paypal_payment.php**

Agradeceré mucho 
Saludos

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no funciona?

Comment: hola, necesito instalarlo no usando ANOUAR, lo que me faltan son los pasos siguientes a "paypal/rest-api-sdk-php:*" para completar la instalación

Answer (score 0):

bueno quizá a alguien le sirva
tengo que crear un file en la carpeta config como por ejemplo: payment-method.php o mercado_pago.php con un contenido parecido a este:

```html
<?php

$acces_token=env('MP_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN');
$secret=env('MP_APP_SECRET');
$id=env('MP_APP_ID');

$use_sandbox=env('SANDBOX_GATEWAYS', true);

if(isset($acces_token)){
 return[
  'app_access_token'=> env('MP_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN')
 ];
}
elseif(isset($id) && isset($secret)){
 return [
  'app_use_sandbox' => env('SANDBOX_GATEWAYS'),
  'app_id'       => env('MP_APP_ID'),
  'app_secret'    => env('MP_APP_SECRET')
 ];
}
else{
    return [
    'app_access_token' => env('MP_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN'),
    'app_id'     => env('MP_APP_ID'),
    'app_secret' => env('MP_APP_SECRET')
    ];
}
```

Token, id y claves secretas las coloco en el archivo env más o menos de esta forma:

MP_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
SANDBOX_GATEWAYS=true
MP_APP_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
MP_APP_SECRET=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx